# Unable to find Exoplayer classes in gradle r2.0.4 repository

Tags: java, android, exoplayer

I am attempting to use the latest versions of exoplayer to access new classes and bug fixes included in the newer builds, unfortunately I am unable to find the exoplayer class in any gradle exoplayer version after r1.5.7, I am unable to even reach com.google.android directory as well which is odd, has anyone encountered this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the issue, turns out the issue wasn't related to exoplayer but instead android studio had cached the older version of exoplayer and did not clear caches even after invalidating and restarting, I had to manually find the hidden cache on my system and delete it this way, that solved the problem.